# How to detect restart of the app by Forever module

Tags: node.js

I have an application with cluster and Forever. I want to save information from workers before shutdown or restart of the app. So I use process.on('SIGINT') and that works fine for CTRL+C.

But I have stuck with Forever. Is it possible to detect somehow the app was restarted by Forever? Is there any signal about that?

Answer (score 3):

This issue is quite old, but for those who did not saw it, the lastest forever versions support --killSignal (this has been added in dec 2013) so you can use by example `--killSignal=SIGUSR2` and catch this signal with `process.on('SIGUSR2', func)`

Answer (score 0):

Forever uses a SIGKILL see https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever-monitor/blob/master/lib/forever-monitor/monitor.js#L353

So add `process.on('SIGKILL', onStop);` to your `process.on('SIGINT', onStop);` though note that after that forever uses `kill` https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever-monitor/blob/master/lib/forever-monitor/common.js#L45 which sends a 'SIGTERM', so `process.on('SIGTERM', onStop)` as well.

Comment: `SIGKILL` can't be caught by a process. If you try in Node, you'll get an `EINVAL` error.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to do `kill -s SIGUSR1 <pid>` before restarting your daemon. This signal can be easily caught in node by `process.on('SIGUSR1')`.

```
kill -s SIGUSR1 <pid>
forever restart test.js
```

Comment: What the point of sending a sigusr just before a sigkill if this does not have the time to do the proper cleans ?

Comment: It's one of workarounds and surely not a complete solution for graceful shutdown. You can use `sleep 30 && forever restart test.js` if you wish btw.

Answer (score 0):

forever has a option --killSignal, you can customize it to other caughtable signals(such as SIGINT), then in your app, use process.on('SIGINT', ...) to caught it. There is a [official example](https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever-monitor/blob/master/examples/graceful-exit.js) , the console.log statements have no effect in signal handler, I think it's a bug, hopes fix soon.